# Export simple .fbx animation to Destinations VR

Tags: animation

I imported a .obj from a CAD software,built a keyframe based translation animation, then exported the .fbx file.

When importing the mesh in Destinations Workshop tool. with de model tool, there is no problem getting the object mesh.

But when I want to import the animation, I'm not able to make it work 
 - without bones it just crash
 - with bones (limp attached to the obj) it doesn't animate

My "not working" model is available [here](http://www.filedropper.com/piston)

Do you have any idea how to manage an animation export to Destinations VR ?

What I'd really like is a simple working animation .blend that I can extrapolate from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 days I managed to graps some of the inner working :

1. There is no problem having multiple separated objects linked to the
   same armature
2. When importing from blender's .fbx, uncheck the
   "convert units to inches from :" checkbox
3. In the mesh, uncheck "skin parented objects" and check "skin parented transforms"
4. Never EVER let anything like : suns, lights or cameras when exporting to .fbx
5. Don't bother painting materials in blender, I
   didn't manage to export them to Destinations, just assign names and
   build them in hammer

I managed to import a 1000+ part .obj in blender, rigged it with 18 bones with three pistons kinematics, and imported four 120 frame animations with ease respecting those five points.

You can find [Here](https://dropfile.to/x1aUfJ1) the simple piston that I rigged to test the import.

Bottom line is: to work with destinations VR you need to learn how to rig.